# Build angular2 app with webpack - can't find ./compiler.es5.ts

Tags: angular, build, webpack

I'm using webpack to build an angular2 app. after upgrading angular2 from 2.3.1 to 4.0.1, webpack is outputting the following `Warning`:

```
WARNING in ./~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js
Cannot find source file 'compiler.es5.ts': Error: Can't resolve 
'./compiler.es5.ts' in '../node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular'
@ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.es5.js 11:0-72
```

The message is correct because there is not such a file with `ts` extension at that location, the file exist but has `js` extension.

Do I mis a webpack configuration value?

BTW: I do not see the warning, if I use @angular/cli v1.0 to build the app.

Comment: It seems that it had to do with the `source-map-loader`. as a work around I excluded all the node_modules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar issue is reported in
https://github.com/angular-redux/store/issues/64

Workaround is adding `exclude` rule for source-map-loader in your webpack.config.js.

```
{
        test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
        exclude: [
            // workaround for this issue
            path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '@angular/compiler')
        ],
        use: [{
            loader: 'source-map-loader'
        }],
        enforce: 'pre'
}
```

But this workaround above is no more than temporary one.

Comment: The error described in the question also occurs when you use angular CLI `ng eject` and this solves it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I also got very similar warning when I was starting the application from a folder that was actually a **symlink** (created via `mklink`). Also the css was then completely broken.

My issue was also related probably to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3797 and https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2726 and disappeared when I started the app from a regular folder.

Comment: This was the solution for me, I was starting it from `C:\Users\ABC\My Documents\Project` instead of `C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Project`, thank you!