# Broken styles when Angular-CLI serves application using webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-bootstrap

I have a weird problem when I try to serve my angular application with angular CLI.

When I run `ng serve`, I get the following message after the compilation :

```
WARNING in C:/Users/tsnr1214/Documents/workspace3/my-project/node_modules/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file 'compiler.es5.ts': Error: Can't resolve './compiler.es5.ts' in 'C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular'
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file 'compiler.es5.ts': Error: Can't resolve './compiler.es5.ts' in 'C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular'
    at emitWarning (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:116:16)
    at C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\source-map-loader\index.js:65:7
    at onError (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:65:10)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:158:4)

    at innerCallback (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:252:11)
    at C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:158:4)

    at innerCallback (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
@ C:/Users/tsnr1214/Documents/workspace3/my-project/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.es5.js 7:0-72
@ C:/Users/tsnr1214/Documents/workspace3/my-project/src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

WARNING in C:/Users/tsnr1214/Documents/workspace3/my-project/node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find SourceMap 'maps/swiper.js.map': Error: Can't resolve './maps/swiper.js.map' in 'C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\swiper\dist\js'
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find SourceMap 'maps/swiper.js.map': Error: Can't resolve './maps/swiper.js.map' in 'C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\swiper\dist\js'
    at emitWarning (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:116:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\source-map-loader\index.js:35:6)
    at onError (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:65:10)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:158:4)

    at innerCallback (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:252:11)
    at C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:158:4)

    at innerCallback (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\tsnr1214\Documents\workspace3\my-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
@ C:/Users/tsnr1214/Documents/workspace3/my-project/node_modules/ng-boosted/o-carousel/o-carousel-container.component.js 10:13-30
@ C:/Users/tsnr1214/Documents/workspace3/my-project/node_modules/ng-boosted/index.js
@ C:/Users/tsnr1214/Documents/workspace3/my-project/src/app/app.module.ts
@ C:/Users/tsnr1214/Documents/workspace3/my-project/src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

Then, if I open my application in the browser, it works but almost all styles are broken (mainly the bootstrap styles).

I found a similar issue here : [Build angular2 app with webpack - can't find ./compiler.es5.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349869/build-angular2-app-with-webpack-cant-find-compiler-es5-ts)

However, I don't have any `webpack.config.js` in my project.

Also, we are 5 to work on this angular project and I am the only one to have this error.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could solve this problem ?

Comment: One of the error says you are missing `swiper.js`, you say there are 5 of you working on the project, perhaps you need to do `npm install` for missing packages or probably update to @angular/compiler

Comment: @12seconds : I used Yarn but I will try `npm install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular-CLI embarks webpack, so most probably your webpack configuration is located in your `.angular-cli.json` file, but if it worked without any issue before and you didn't change anything, I'd suggest you try to delete your folder `node_modules`, uninstall / reinstall `@angular/cli` globally (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) and try to serve your application again.

Comment: After many uninstall / reinstall of @angular/cli and after moving the project from one repertory to another, that works. I think there is 2 possible causes : 1) On my computer, I had some traces of the old name "angular-cli" 2) Sometimes, the "Documents" repertory of Windows becomes "My Documents" with a space, and spaces may cause problems.

Comment: This could also be due to administrator rights on certains files (for example read-only `node_modules`), even though it should not happens but sometimes folders get some weird options I guess